# How can I bundle Javascript and CSS files to a specific folder with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

I'm trying to get Webpack to build Javascript and CSS files to their respective folders. I'm fairly new to Webpack and I can't seem to find the exact plugin that'll help me do this.

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
dist
   |___js
   |     |__app.js
   |     |__vendor.js
   |
   |___css
   |      |__style.css
   |
   |___index.html
```

[image]

**The config file:**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",

    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/app.js")
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
        clean: true
    },

    devtool: "inline-source-map",

    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        port: 5001,
        open:true,
        hot: true,
        watchContentBase: true
    },

    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "main.html",
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.html")}), 

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "main.css"
        })
            ],

    module: {
        rules: [    
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },

            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I haven't made myself clear, Please feel free to ask me any questions.

Comment: What do you mean with _"build Javascript and CSS files"_?

Comment: @Thomas Sabik, Thank you for responding. Essentially, I want all my Javascript and CSS files from my **src** folder to be bundled and outputted into their respective folders which is under the **dist** folder meaning the "js" folder should have all the javascript files and the "css" folder should have all the css files. Am I being clear?

Comment: Didn't know Webpack creates CSS files. Usually the styles are included in the JavaScript modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the filename property that you're passing to MiniCssExtractPlugin to `"css/style.css"`

Comment: Thanks for responding but, That doesn't seem to work...

Comment: What happens when you try? Does it build the files properly, but not import the css, or something else entirely?

Comment: The js files do get built but not the css files. So I added another entry pointing to my css file like so: `styles: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/css/style.css")`. This does get the job done but, It also adds a "styles.js" file to my js folder :/ [Here's the updated config file](https://pastebin.com/teDmiUA2)

Comment: After a few more hours of banging my head against the wall.... I realized I was never importing my style.css file into my app.js file. Thank you for your answer, I'll go flush myself down the toilet :)

Comment: That was a great answer , thanks